# Цвет пикселей из BitmapImage

Tags: c#, bitmap

У меня есть `BitmapIamge`, это png 100 на 100 пикселей. Я обыскал весь интернет и нашел метод `copyPixels`, только я не знаю как его юзать. У меня с то выскакивают ошибки, то цвет всегда чёрный. Кто-нибудь может написать рабочий метод для получения цвета из `BitmapImage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо сначала сконвертировать `BitmapImage` в `Bitmap`

```
    private static Bitmap BitmapImage2Bitmap(BitmapSource bitmapImage)
    {
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(outStream);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

А уже затем получить нужный пиксель:

```
        var url = new Uri("D:\\1.png");
        var bi = new BitmapImage(url);
        var bm = BitmapImage2Bitmap(bi);
        var pixel = bm.GetPixel(x, y);
```

Где `x` и `y` - координаты пикселя от левого верхнего угла.
Цвет в формате `RGB` будет доступен из полей `pixel.R` `pixel.G` `pixel.B` для красного, зеленого и синего соответственно и `pixel.A` - для альфаканала.

Comment: Импортировал System.Drawing, а типа Bitmap нету, это в WPF. Как так то?

Comment: В смысле `using System.Drawing;` в заголовке добавили? А ссылки на сборку в проект добавили?

Comment: Ссылку на сборку? В referenses что ли?

Comment: Да, именно туда.

Comment: Всё, сделал. Спасибо большое